# Add to cart items from input field (only numbers 1-999 )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have an input box where I want, after clicking the add to cart button, to change the value of the basket. I want to do this through the script:

```
<script>
                     let localStorage = window.localStorage;
                     var CartCounter = localStorage.getItem('CartCounter') === null ? 0 : localStorage.getItem('CartCounter');

                     $(".cart-wish").text(CartCounter);

                     $(document).ready(function(){
                         $(".accordion-heading").click(function(){
                             if($(".accordion-body").is(':visible')){  /* check the condition accordion-body is visible or not */
                                 $(".accordion-body").slideUp(200);  /*if content is visible then close accordion-body with specific time duration */
                                 $(".plusminus").text('+')    /* add plus sign */
                             }
                             else{
                                 $(this).next(".accordion-body").slideDown(200); /*if content not visible then
                                                                                                                               show the accordion-body */
                                 $(this).children(".plusminus").text('-');  /* add minus sign */
                             }
                         });
                         $(".add-to-cart").click(function(){
                             CartCounter++;
                             localStorage.setItem('CartCounter', CartCounter);
                             $(".cart-wish").text(CartCounter);

                         });
                     });

                 </script>
```

It at the same time this script stores the variable in cache.

HTML input group and Add to Cart button:

```
<div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-white btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
                        </span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control no-padding add-color text-center height-15" maxlength="3" value="0">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-red btn-pluss" type="button">+</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">ADD TO CART</button>
```

Script for input group:

```
<script>
                            $('.btn-minuse').on('click', function(){
                $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) - 1)
        })

        $('.btn-pluss').on('click', function(){
                $(this).parent().siblings('input').val(parseInt($(this).parent().siblings('input').val()) + 1)
        })
              </script>
```

Thank you!